# Calling a method for an OBJ stored within map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am playing with JAVA, and wanted to simulate an ATM System. I have a class for a BankMember(int accountNumber, int pin, int balance, String name) and a UserDatabase using a HashMap 
the key will be the accountNumber, and I want to store the BankMember within the HashMap.

I have a UserInterface that will accept account number's and pins, and attempt to login to the UserDatabase.

I am able to store the OBJs into the HashMap without an issue, but when I attempt to call methods from within BankMember I get nullPointerExceptions.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atm.UserDatabase.validateLogin(UserDatabase.java:65)
    at atm.TheBank.login(TheBank.java:46)
    at atm.UserInterface.validateLogin(UserInterface.java:38)
    at atm.UserInterface.login(UserInterface.java:31)
    at atm.ATM.main(ATM.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

I understand that my BankMember is not running the method call correctly, but I don't know how to work around this. Should I not even use a HashMap for this?

This is my userDatabase class

```
package atm;
import java.util.HashMap;
/**
 *
 * @author Hybrid
 */
public class UserDatabase {
    BankMember bankMember;
    private int currentAccount; //when a user logs in, the currentAccount is stored for quick access to the EU's key
    private HashMap<Integer, BankMember> accountNumberAndMember; //account number, BankMember

    public UserDatabase() {
        bankMember = new BankMember();
        currentAccount = 0;
        accountNumberAndMember = new HashMap<Integer, BankMember>();
    }

    public boolean validateAccountNumberAvailable(int accountNumber) {
        boolean validate = true;
        if (accountNumberAndMember.containsKey(accountNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Account # already in use: "+ accountNumber);
            validate = false;
        }
        return validate;
    }

    private boolean validateAccountExists(int accountNumber) {
        boolean validate = true;
        if (accountNumberAndMember.containsKey(accountNumber)) {
            validate = true;
        }
        return validate;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param accountNumber validate the account number is not already in the database.
     * @param bankMember if the account number is not already used, then the bankMember is stored within the database
     * @return  true is bankMember stored, false if not
     */
    public boolean setUpNewUser(int accountNumber, int pin, int balance, String name) {
        boolean validate = true;
        if(!accountNumberAndMember.containsKey(accountNumber)) {
            bankMember = new BankMember(accountNumber, pin, balance, name);
            System.out.println("Member stored in database with key: " + accountNumber);
            accountNumberAndMember.put(accountNumber, bankMember);
            System.out.println(accountNumberAndMember.get(accountNumber).getName()+ " was stored in the map as a new user.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This account has already been created\nAccount Number:"+accountNumber);
            validate = false;
        }
        return validate;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param accountNumber this is the key for accountNumberAndMember map
     * @param pin this is tested within the BankMember to verify it is truly them attempting to login.
     * @return true is login is successful. False if not with proper error message.
     */
    public boolean validateLogin(int accountNumber, int pin) {
        System.out.println("::::::::::::LOGIN SYSTEM::::::::::::");
        boolean validate = validateAccountExists(accountNumber);
        if(validate) {
            System.out.println("\n\n" + accountNumberAndMember.get(accountNumber).getName()); // THIS FAILS
            if(accountNumber == accountNumberAndMember.get(accountNumber).getAccountNumber()) { //if account number is within the map
                if(pin == (accountNumberAndMember.get(accountNumber).getPin())) {
                    System.out.println("Login successful");
                    currentAccount = accountNumberAndMember.get(accountNumber).getAccountNumber();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Pin: " + pin);
                    validate = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Account Number: "+ accountNumber);
                validate = false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The account number does not exist: " + accountNumber);
        }
        return validate;
    }

    //Resetting Map key
    public void logOff() {
        currentAccount = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validateAccountExists` method always returns `true`, no matter what. It would be better to simply

```
return accountNumberAndMember.containsKey(accountNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks - With that fixed, now I get System.out.println("The account number does not exist: " +accountNumber); , which is my orig problem.

Comment: @Eplachta Where are you populating `accountNumberAndMember`?

Comment: @MikeB within public boolean setUpNewUser() { accountNumberAndMember.put(accountNumber, bankMember); }

Comment: @Eplachta And you've verified the contents of it with the debugger at the time you call `validateAccountExists()`? Or at least printed out the contents of it where you check if it contains the account number you're validating?

Comment: @MikeB Thank you for the input. I validated it was searching for the accountNumber, but my hashMap was not getting valid values. What you said made me look back at my BankMember and found my mistake. Forgot to delete a single line that was setting each members account number to 0, which was breaking the entire program. 

Thank you so much!